# JQuery Mobile cannot pull GPS coordinates into googlemaps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, mobile, gps

I have a div mobile page for an app i am building. When I define:

```
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
```

Either within my function or even outside it, and then try and use them in:

```
latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

My page does not load, and only gives me the css borders e.t.c

However, if I simply remove `(latitude, longitude);` and put in `(40.716948, -74.003563);`
into `latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);` it works.

**Why are the defined variable values not passing into LatLng ?**

Here is the div part of the source:

```
<!-- My Location -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="my_loc" class="page-map1">

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <a href="#home" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
    <h1>My Location</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">

    <h2>Map</h2>

    <div id="map1" class="gmap"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var map1, latlng1, options1, latitude, longitude;

        //these lat and long variable definitions are messing me up !!
        //latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        //longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        function initialize() { 
          latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          //40.716948, -74.003563);
          //Lat, Lon); 
          //(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          //40.716948, -74.003563); change from new jersey
          options1 = { zoom: 14, center: latlng1, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
          map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), options1);
        }

        $('.page-map1').live("pagecreate", function() {
          initialize();
        });

        $('.page-map1').live('pageshow',function(){
          console.log("test");
          google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize');
          map1.setOptions(options1); 
        });
      </script>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div data-role="page" id="map" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Page Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p class="errorMsg">Your location could not be determined.</p>
      <div id="gMap"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h4>TRACK</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /My Location -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you fix the `enter code here`s?

Comment: I am not a jquery guy or know anything about what you are trying to do, but it sure looks like where you set the value for `latitude` and `longitude` are commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Your longitude and latitude variables are obviously not being populated. In order for them to be populated, surely you need to call the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition method first? But even before that stage, you want to ensure that geolocation is supported by the browser (check the navigator.geolocation boolean).

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) and align your logic to be a bit more like this. Once you've done that, alert/console.log your longitude and latitude vars to ensure that they are actually being populated.